# Is Cassandra able to detect corrupted data that doesn't get used often?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, data-corruption

Is there anything like HDFS's DataBlockScanner for Cassandra, ie. an automatic mechanism that checks for corrupted data that doesn't get read often?

Answer (score 2):

No.

> Cassandra doesn't do that automatically - it can guarantee consistency on
>   read or write via ConsistencyLevel on each query, and it can run active
>   (AntiEntropy) repairs. But active repairs must be scheduled (by human or
>   cron or by third party script like http://cassandra-reaper.io/), and to
>   be pedantic, repair only fixes consistency issue, there's some work to be
>   done to properly address/support fixing corrupted replicas (for example,
>   repair COULD send a bit flip from one node to all of the others)

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201709.mbox/%3CCABNXB2CWXqvR_zkGSGfw7DJjU+Emer3a0Dcv0YkHUtKBEc1e+A@mail.gmail.com%3E

Big data as a trash can. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to use `nodetool verify` to compare the hash of the sstable with the content. Particularly with `nodetool verify -e` to walk the individual cells.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsVerify.html